# Count group by, and add category for disabled

Tags: sql, view, group-by, mariadb

I have a table of `Automate` define like this :

```
Colonne Type
id          int(11) Incrément automatique   
name        varchar(255)    
type        varchar(255)    
code        varchar(255)    
password    varchar(255)    
active      tinyint(1)
```

i make view like this for my dashboard:

```
SELECT COUNT('type') as count, type as name
FROM automate
GROUP BY type;
```

But this didn't take care if automate is activated or not ...
In first place i want to remove inactivated automate from the report 
( easy with adding a simple `where activated = 1`)

But how can i add a fake `type` for counting unactivated automate ?

Actual result:

```
| type   | count |
| comx   |     4 |
| gateway|     3 |
```

Wanted Result :

```
| type        | count |
| comx        |     1 |
| gateway     |     2 |
| unactivated |     4 |
```

(assuming `type` come from a enum, and can't have `unactivated` value in bdd)

Comment: . . Sample data, desired results and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using conditional aggregation:

```
select
    type,
    count(*) cnt,
    sum(case when active = 1 then 1 else 0 end) activated,
    sum(case when active = 0 then 1 else 0 end) inactivated
from automate
group by type
```

For each type, the query gives you the total count of records, the count of of records where `active = 1`, and the count of records where `active = 0`.

---

In MariaDB, that you finally tagged your question with, the query can be simplified a little:

```
select
    type,
    count(*) cnt,
    sum(active = 1) activated,
    sum(active = 0) inactivated
from automate
group by type
```

Answer (score 0):

If `active` can only take on the values of `0` and `1`, then you can use:

```
SELECT type, SUM(active) as num_active,
       SUM(1 - active) as num_inactive
FROM automate
GROUP BY type;
```

If you want to add them as a different row, then:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(*) as num_active,
       SUM(1 - active) as num_inactive
FROM automate
WHERE active = 1
GROUP BY type
UNION ALL
SELECT 'inactive', 0, COUNT(*)
FROM automate
WHERE active = 0;
```

Comment: the second request didn't work : The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns